# Dynamically setting xml by string concatenation

Tags: xml, apache-flex, actionscript-3, adobe, mxml

I'm trying to read xml fields (with actionscript 3), but the problem is that I choose which field to read dynamically. For example, I may need to read `test19` or `test39` or `test12` or anything else.

```
var value:Number = event.result.test19;
var value:Number = event.result.test39;
var value:Number = event.result.test12;
```

Is there a way to construct that `event.result.test19` part dynamically? Something like the code idea below

```
var fieldname:String = "test19";
var value:Number = ("event.result." + fieldname) as Number;
```

I also tried casting as XMLNode `("event.result." + fieldname) as XMLNode` but it didn't work.

Anyone knows how this can be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var value:Number = event.result["test19"];
//or 
var t:String = "test19";
var value:Number = event.result[t];
```

`obj.something` is same as `obj["something"]` and `obj[a_var]` where `a_var` contains `"something."`

Comment: Perfect answer Amarghosh. Thank you.